# Handle documents in Lucene with negated term(s)

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, nlp

Is it possible to build index in Lucene in a way that it will consider negative context?

So if text contains **"not black car"** searching by query **"black car"** will not return this document as relevant?

Do I need to write my own [Analyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html)? Or there are existing solutions or better ways?

If important documents are in Finnish language.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment I am using following solution with custom filter but still interested in better one:

I've wrote custom `TokenFilter` named `NegationFilter` that reads terms from underlying `TokenStream` and if it finds some negative words (*"ei"*, *"eivät"* in Finnish; *"no", "not"* in English) it appends suffix **"-not"** to several following terms (number of this terms controlled with `negationTraceSize` variable)

So **"not black car"** will be parsed to `[black-not, car]` or `[black-not, car-not]` with `negationTraceSize = 2`

It is still needs improvements because it will not recognize phrases like "not really black car" or "not black or yellow car" but will work in simple cases.

code in scala, if interested:

```
final class NegationFilter(input: TokenStream,
                     negations: Set[String], negationTraceSize: Int = 2
                      ) extends TokenFilter(input) {
  private val termAtt = addAttribute(classOf[CharTermAttribute])
  private val posInc = addAttribute(classOf[org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionIncrementAttribute])

  private var inNegative: Boolean = false
  private var negativeOffset: Int = 0

  override def reset(): Unit = {
    super.reset()
    inNegative = false
    negativeOffset = 0
  }

  override def incrementToken(): Boolean = {
    if (input.incrementToken) {
      if (negations(termAtt.toString)) {
        inNegative = true
        negativeOffset = 0
        return incrementToken()
      } else {
        negativeOffset = negativeOffset + posInc.getPositionIncrement
        if (negativeOffset > negationTraceSize) {
          inNegative = false
        }
      }
      if (inNegative) {
        termAtt.append("-not")
      }
      return true
    }
    else {
      return false
    }
  }
}
```